# Why is my background darker than it should be?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have a website I made with bootstrap, specifically material design bootstrap.

My regular background is darker than I want it to be, does anybody know why?
My website: https://vanetech.000webhostapp.com/

It won't let me paste my code so view it @
https://0paste.com/29373

Comment: I voted to close as this question will be useless to future users in 48 hours - 10 days. (_Ghostbin will be shutting down in May 2019.
Until then, all newly-created pastes will expire in 48 hours._)

Comment: FYI, of course you can paste code, as long as it is done within SO guidelines. Regarding your content, reread [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Do note, the essential part of the code should be **within** the question, for the same reason I wrote in my first comment (when an external resource dies, so does the question and its answers).

Comment: it wont let me post it bcause it had an image in it and i have less than 10 posts

Comment: srry tho i updated code source

Comment: Then you simply post code w/o image.

Comment: but the thing im tryin fix is the image

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: If you mean this when it comes to post an image, then no: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268469/why-cant-users-with-less-than-10-reputation-points-add-images-while-asking-ques ... if you mean code handling an image, then yes, that can be posted by users having reps. lower than 10 as well.

Comment: Please read (my) 2nd comment above, it links to what is required when posting questions.

Answer (score -1):

You overlay your background with `.rgba-stylish-strong`. If you remove that class, you will see a much brighter background.